# How to print Chinese Characters in DataNitro?

Tags: python, excel, datanitro

I am new to DataNitro. I want to deal with some Chinese Characters in my excel sheet but fail.

When I print Chinese Characters in Python Shell, everything is right. However, when I print Chinese Characters in an imported python file, it tells me `UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 36: illegal multibyte sequence.`

I think codec should be utf-8 so I tried adding headers below. But this still doesn't work.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Hope some one could give me some tips. Thanks.

Comment: Which characters are you trying to print?

Comment: I am trying to `print("中文")`

Comment: Dear Ben, I tried but still can not solve this problem. I could print Chinese character(say, `print('中文')`) in the shell and outside of Datanitro. However, I couldn't print in Datanitro(say, import a file). This troubles me a lot and I can not move on. Could you help give me some hint, so I can go further. Thanks.